# JMeter error rate too high despite successful requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Update - Deleting the Aggregate report and rerunning the test now gives an error rate of 0. Why is this required?

I am using JMeter 4.0 to hit a REST web service with 20 thread groups by sending a POST request with a JSON body. All 20 requests succeed and give proper response (200 with a correct JSON body). Why is the error rate above 99%? (See image below). Also, why is no of samples is 10063 in report even though View Results Tree tab shows 20 HTTP requests (each with error count 0).

[image]

Comment: what version of jmeter are you running ? is it in gui mode ?

Comment: JMeter 4.0 in GUI mode

Answer (score 1):

If you run JMeter test which assumes 20 HTTP Request and seeing > 10 000 in the listener - most probably you are opening an incorrect .jtl results file in the listener.

1. Double check that "Filename" input field is empty

   [image]
2. Prior to running a new test make sure to clean "in-memory" results by choosing `Run -> Clear All` from JMeter's main menu (or click Control+E)

   [image: JMeter Clear All]

---

Be aware that [using Listeners is a some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing), they don't add any value but consume valuable system resources which can be either used for something else or left intact to save the trees. So:

1. Remove all the listeners from the test plan
2. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. When your test is finished either open JMeter GUI and inspect the `result.jtl` file with the listener of your choice (you can load it using aforementioned "Filename" tab)
4. Or generate an [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of the `result.jtl` file - it will contain statistical information, tables and charts outlining your test results.

Answer (score 0):

View Results Tree since few versions only keep last 500 SampleResult and only refreshes every few seconds.

So the number of samples in view results tree is not the total.

Besides, you should never run a load test in GUI mode as it impacts negatively performances of Jmeter injection.

see this for best practices :

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/